# SQL - Select distinct row with multiple categories

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, razor

I have three database tables:

Story

- Id
- Title
- Content

Category

- Id
- Title

StoryCategory

- StoryId
- CategoryId

Note: Story and Category has a many-to-many relationship (a story can have multiple categories and a category can have multiple stories) so I created the StoryCategory. Also, a story can have no category.

I also have a web page (I'm using razor):

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <label for="keyword">Keyword:</label>
    <input name="keyword" type="text" value="@Page.Keyword" />
    <label for="category">Category:</label>
    <select name="category">
        <option value="">All</option>
    @foreach(var category in Page.Categories)
    {
        <option value=@category.Id @(category.Id == Page.Category? "selected=selected" : "")>@category.Title</option>
    }
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

To make it simple, this page allows the user to enter a keyword to search for specific story and it also allows the user to select the category which the story belongs to.

I can't find a way to find the stories attached to a specific category. Here's my first code (keyword disregarded to focus on category):

```
select s.title --columns will be added here such as name of category/ies, author etc.
from story as s
left join --left join so the uncategorized stories will not be excluded
storyCategory as sc
on s.id = sc.storyId
where sc.categoryId = @selectedCategory --this line is removed when there is no category selected
```

Sample Data:

- Story

  id    title   content
  1     naruto  ...
  2     bleach  ...
- Category

  id    title
  1     fantasy
  2     action
  3     drama
- StoryCategory

  storyId   categoryId
  1         1
  1         2
  2         1

The problem is, if there is no selected category and if story has multiple categories, it will appear also multiple times:

```
naruto (fantasy)
naruto (action)
bleach (fantasy)
```

I actually know what is happening but I can't think of a best solution to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT keyword and left join is useless with your WHERE condition

```
select DISTINCT
  s.title --columns will be added here such as name of category/ies, author etc.
from story as s
join storyCategory as sc--left join so the uncategorized stories will not be excluded
on s.id = sc.storyId
where sc.categoryId = @selectedCategory --this line is removed when there is no category selected
```

If you need the list of categories attached to each story - see and examine the next query. Valid for sql server:

```
DECLARE @Stories TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, NAME NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL) 
DECLARE @Categories TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, NAME NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL) 
DECLARE @Fork TABLE(StoryId INT NOT NULL, CategoryId INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(StoryId, CategoryId)) 

INSERT @Stories 
VALUES ('Story1'), ('Story2'), ('Story3') 

INSERT @Categories 
VALUES ('Category1'), ('Category2'), ('Category3') 

INSERT @Fork 
VALUES(1,1), (1,2), (3,3), (2,3) 

DECLARE @selectedCategory INT = 3 

select 
s.NAME, 
( 
SELECT c.Name + ',' 
FROM @Categories c 
JOIN @Fork f ON f.CategoryId = c.Id AND f.StoryId = s.Id 
ORDER BY c.Name 
FOR XML PATH('') 
) Categories 
from @stories s
```

Comment: I hate when I'm typing out an answer and see 'A new answer has been posted'... Refresh and you've beaten to it. Suppose I'll have to be happy with upvoting you then :)

Comment: @Michael Everybody hate this 8-) But there is always an opportunity to learn something

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Actually - not, sometimes I answered the question after hours and when there were 5 other answers. And I still got +7 upvotes. So - never give up! 8-)

Comment: @Oleg, as I have said, I'll be adding columns such as categories and stuffs, if I add them to distinct, wouldn't it be a problem?

Comment: @domanokz It will, so now the question is - what you really want - one story and concatenated list of categories or two queries - one for stories, one for corresponding categories etc... And it now depends on which port of SQL you use

Comment: Also, the where clause is removed whenever there is not category selected (i concatenate it thru app codes), the left join is not useless.

Comment: Yes :) concatenated list of categories. I think that's another question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6599/discussion-between-oleg-dok-and-domanokz)

Comment: @OlegDok: but faster typing skill doesn't hurt :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limiting it to a single category, try something like this:

```
select s.title,count(*) as NumCategories 
from story as s
left join storyCategory as sc on s.id = sc.storyId
group by s.title
```

You could also find some categories using something like, which shows the number of categories and the first and last (based on title characters) categories the story is in

```
select s.title,count(*) as NumCategories,min(sc.title),max(sc.title)
from story as s
left join storyCategory as sc on s.id = sc.storyId
group by s.title
```